# Suppose that the prime $p$ is totally ramified in $O_{K_1}$ and unramified in $O_{K_2}$. Prove that $K_1 \cap K_2=\Bbb Q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be algebraic number fields. Suppose that the prime $p$ is totally ramified in $O_{K_1}$ and unramified in $O_{K_2}$. Prove that $K_1 \cap K_2=\Bbb Q$.

For unramified $<p>=P_1^{e_1}$ where all $e_1=[K_1:\Bbb Q]$ in $K_1$ and $<p>=Q_1\cdots Q_s$ in $K_2$. Do we get anything from here? You can downvote me but pls give some hint!

Edit: After putting some thought and reading comments(thanks to Jyrki) I thinjk that I have to consider the tower

```
 $ K_1K_2
  /     \
 /       \ 
K_1       K_2
\         /
 \       /
   K_1\cap K_2
       |
       |
      \Bbb Q$
```

Then we have to consider some fixed field...

Comment: Hints: 1) Ramification exponent is multiplicative in a tower. 2) There is a difference between *ramified* and *Totally ramified*. Look it up from you textbook/lecture notes.

Comment: As for ways of avoiding downvotes, study [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: What I am getting from my textbook is the definition of ramified and unramified. Ramified one is $\exists$ one i s.t $e_i>1$. I am not getting the definition of totally ramified in terms of factorisation of $<p>$, in google I am getting something related to Galois theory that I can't understand.If possible can you give me some more hints or the answer as I am stuck on this question for long and losing my patience? I will learn with time on how to ask good question.

Comment: *Totally ramified* means that $\langle p\rangle=\mathfrak{P}^n$ with $n=[K_1:\Bbb{Q}]$. But why would anyone ask you this question without explaining what totally ramified means?

Comment: No, I am solving it by myself and got stuck in some questions. It is self-reading for me from Alaca Williams and I might miss the totally ramified definition. I am searching index and all but I can't find it. That is why I am saying that I am losing patience or going out of my mind. See if you can give me the answer. By the way, I have edited the question with your help. Thanks for that atleast

Comment: Thanks for adding the tower. Sorry about forgetting your question for a few days.

Comment: The notion of *totally ramified* is mentioned very briefly in Alaca and Williams book on page 259 just before theorem 10.5.2 (which gives a sufficient condition for a prime to be totally ramified).

Answer (score 5):

This follows from the definitions, basic properties of the splitting of primes in an extension, in particular the multiplicativity of the ramification exponent.

Denote $M=K_1\cap K_2$. All we need is the tower $\Bbb{Q}\subseteq M\subseteq K_1$.

- Because $p$ is totally ramified in $K_1/\Bbb{Q}$, there exists a unique prime ideal $\mathfrak{P}$ of $\mathcal{O}_{K_1}$ lying above $p$. Furthermore,
  $$p\mathcal{O}_{K_1}=\mathfrak{P}^e,$$ where $e=n=[K_1:\Bbb{Q}]$.
- Let us consider the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}=M\cap \mathfrak{P}.$ The multiplicativity of the ramification exponent implies that
  $$e(\mathfrak{P}|p)=e(\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p})\cdot e(\mathfrak{p}|p).$$
  Here $e(\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p})\le [K_1:M]$ and $e(\mathfrak{p}|p)\le [M:\Bbb{Q}]$. As $[K_1:\Bbb{Q}]=[K_1:M]\cdot [M:\Bbb{Q}]$, we must have equality in both cases, for otherwise $e(\mathfrak{P}|p)$ would be less than $n$.
- So if $[M:\Bbb{Q}]=m>1$ we would see $\mathfrak{p}^m$ in the decomposition of $p$ in $\mathcal{O}_M$. In other words, $p$ ramifies in $M/\Bbb{Q}$.
- But, $M$ is also a subfield of $K_2$. If $p$ ramified in $M/\Bbb{Q}$ it would also ramify in $K_2/\Bbb{Q}$ (again by multiplicativity of $e$). We were given that this is not the case, so we can conclude that $m=1$.
- Hence $K_1\cap K_2=M=\Bbb{Q}$.

Parts of the argument generalize to the following two maxims:

> If a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ is totally ramified in a finite extension of number fields $L/K$, then it is (totally) ramified also in all the intermediate extensions $L/M, M/K$ where $K\subseteq M\subseteq L$.
>
> If a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ is unramified in a finite extension of number fields $L/K$, then all primes lying above it are unramified in all the intermediate extensions $L/M, M/K$ where $K\subseteq M\subseteq L$.

Comment: Somewhat surprisingly I could not find a thread, where this would be spelled out.

Comment: +1 there, I was studying the book *Introductory Algebraic Number Theory* by Alaca and Williams (which contains this exercise in chapter on factorization of prime ideals), but I didn't find this multiplicative nature of ramification index discussed in the chapter. They only discuss ramification in absolute terms (ie $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq K$) and not relatively as in $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq K\subseteq L$. I wonder if they had some other approach in mind while creating this exercise.